# Mailer: email is empty, can't figure out why

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, there is controller method:

```
  def send_feedback
  if params[:f_message].length!=0
  if current_user && current_user.email
    UserMailer.feedback_email(current_user.email, params[:f_name], params[:f_message]).deliver
    redirect_to root_url,  :notice=>"Thank you for contacting us"
  else
    UserMailer.feedback_email(params[:f_email], params[:f_name], params[:f_message]).deliver
    redirect_to root_url,  :notice=>"Thank you for contacting us"
  end
  else
  redirect_to "/info/feedback", :notice=>"Your message is empty... Please be a little bit more informative"
  end
  end
```

And server logs on submiting feedback form:

```
Started POST "/info/send_feedback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-30 15:50:23 +0400
Processing by InfoController#send_feedback as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9yht/zb6RqAlpOJeLPTKpAxvINzWAqFJJHkZE+6hv1Q=", "f_email"=>"", "f_name"=>"", "f_message"=>"test" }
```

(So I'm getting params and passing them to `feedback_email`):

```
  def feedback_email(email, name, message)
    mail :to => "support@*******.com", :subject => "feedback"
    @mail=email
    @name=name
    @message=message
  end
```

With template:

```
From: <%=@name.inspect %>
Mail: <%= @mail.inspect %>
<%= @message.inspect %>
```

And finally, server logs of sending email:

```
Sent mail to *** (2045ms)
Date: Sun, 30 Jun 2013 15:50:23 +0400
From: from@example.com
To: support@*******.com
Message-ID: <51d01b7f2a183_15902ec382492cf@HP-PC.mail>
Subject: feedback
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
From: nil
Mail: nil
nil

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

But, it is empty. Why?

Comment: @Mischa, I double checked, yes, but mail doesn't see variables `@name`, `@message`, `@mail`.

Comment: @Mischa, I also edited, added inspect to variables, take a look on output. About params... I'm not quite sure, there are no params in request, but they are in server log as Parametrs=>{} query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the variables before you send the email, not after:

```
def feedback_email(email, name, message)
  @mail    = email
  @name    = name
  @message = message

  mail :to => "support@*******.com", :subject => "feedback"
end
```

Comment: wow, thanks, it would take me forever to figure out by myself... Actually, the order or defining variables and calling method usually doesn't matter... Or I thought so

Comment: It usually does matter. `mail` invokes the view in which those variables are used, but they don't exist yet. Hence an empty email. I can't think of any situation where defining the variable afterwards would work. Anyway, glad I could help solve your problem.